# Fatal error: Call to undefined function checkdnsrr()

Tags: php

My application checks MX-records on the registration page. It works fine on my local development machine (Windows 7 with *WAMP Server*) and on my hosting account (Linux server). Recently I deployed the app on another hosting account and I got the following error when I tried to register an user:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function checkdnsrr() in
>   D:\home\memorytreephoto.com\wwwroot\MyCMS\controls\register\validate_email.php
>   on line 27

My code is below:

```
<?php
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// VALIDATE E-MAIL
// ------------------------------------------------------------
if (!filter_var($txbEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $emailNotValid = $email_error;
    $emailvalidate_error = 1;
}

if (filter_var($txbEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    if (domain_exists($txbEmail)) {
        $emailvalidate_error = 0;
    } else {
        $emailNotValid = $emailmx_error;
        $emailvalidate_error = 1;
    }
}

// Check if MX-records are present
function domain_exists($emailtocheck, $record = 'MX') {
    list($user, $domain) = preg_split('/@/', $emailtocheck);
    return checkdnsrr($domain, $record);
}
?>
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Don't check emails this silly way. You won't get anything useful

Comment: ...and your answer is???

Comment: @Scott what he is saying is that this approach is flawed and unreliable, and you may be better off not performing that particular check altogether.

Comment: which check would be better not performed. the above code is only a snippet. the email address is validated more than one ways. if you not sure what is going on, please ask a question. the one sentence insults are not the way to provide help...

Comment: @Scott true, true. I don't have much practical experience with this but I have come across instances where MX records were not obtainable even though there was a valid domain and E-Mail address present. There is the possibility of false negatives, and timeouts. On the other hand, it is a nice check agains `dfdafa@safasdfkjasdf.com` addresses

Comment: There's actually a delete button. Use that next time

Comment: @Rafe: that's not useable if there are voted or accepted answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A look in the [manual](http://www.php.net/checkdnsrr) shows that this function exists on Windows only since PHP 5.3.0. You'd have to upgrade to that PHP version to make the function work.

Alternatively, there is a [PEAR Class](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS) that provides the functionality to PHP versions < 5.3.0

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was suspecting. The hosting account says: PHP version: 5.x

Comment: @Scott W. You can find out detailled information about your hoster's version of php by writing <?php phpinfo(); in a file and requesting it.

Comment: Pear Class validate.php file also use checkdnsrr to check domain names. So Pear class is not useful for this if php version is less than 5.3.0

Answer (score 1):

This function is only available in PHP 5.3.0 or higher if you're running Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to remove the checkdnsrr from disable_functions at php.ini file or maybe your hosting provider do not have this fuction in the php.ini.  Check this also, another ideas about PHP version.