# Email validation error in PHP

Tags: php

I have build up a form and and link a `emailvalidation.php` to send the data on my mail. I am facing an error in my PHP code on line 37. I don't know where is the error.

> Error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function `checkdnsrr()` in `G:\PleskVhosts\domain.com\httpdocs\php\functions\emailValidation.php` on line 37

PHP code:

```
<?php
function validEmail($emailaddress) {
    $isValid = true;
    $atIndex = strrpos($emailaddress, "@");
    if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex) {
        $isValid = false;
    } else {
        $domain = substr($emailaddress, $atIndex + 1);
        $local = substr($emailaddress, 0, $atIndex);
        $localLen = strlen($local);
        $domainLen = strlen($domain);
        if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64) {
            // local part length exceeded
            $isValid = false;
        } else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255) {
            // domain part length exceeded
            $isValid = false;
        } else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen - 1] == '.') {
            // local part starts or ends with '.'
            $isValid = false;
        } else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local)) {
            // local part has two consecutive dots
            $isValid = false;
        } else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain)) {
            // character not valid in domain part
            $isValid = false;
        } else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain)) {
            // domain part has two consecutive dots
            $isValid = false;
        } else if (!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/', str_replace("\\\\", "", $local))) {
            // character not valid in local part unless
            // local part is quoted
            if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/', str_replace("\\\\", "", $local))) {
                $isValid = false;
            }
        }
        if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain, "MX") || checkdnsrr($domain, "A"))) {
            // domain not found in DNS
            $isValid = false;
        }
    }
    return $isValid;
}
?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It would help if you posted what error is being displayed.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function checkdnsrr() in G:\PleskVhosts\domain.com\httpdocs\php\functions\emailValidation.php on line 37

Comment: You're running the wrong version of PHP for checkdnsrr() to work properly. Check out this answer here, it should help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541484/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-checkdnsrr

Comment: so what would be alternative for this code ?

Answer (score -1):

you call this

```
checkdnsrr
```

and that function is not supported in your php version